# Using dynamically-allocated arrays causes spurious C6386 Buffer Overrun warning from Code Analysis

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, static-analysis, code-analysis

*(Note: This question relates to an incorrect spurious C6386 warning from the code analysis. It is not a duplicate of questions asking about genuine instances of that warning)*

When I use a dynamically-allocated array in C++ I get a spurious [C6386 warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6386?view=vs-2019) issued from the Visual Studio 2019 Code Analysis.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```cpp
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> someInts{ 1, 2, 3 };

    int* dynamicInts = new int[someInts.size()];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < someInts.size(); i++)
    {
        dynamicInts[i] = someInts[i];
    }

    delete[] dynamicInts;
}
```

The intent here is that we have a vector of ints and we want to copy them to a dynamically-allocated array of ints for some reason. (Slightly silly example but it shows the problem).

**Note that the code uses the `size()` of the `someInts` vector during allocation of the `dynamicInts` array AND as the upper bound of the loop, so there should never be an issue with buffer overrun.**

Yet code analysis generates:

```
main.cpp(11): warning C6386: Buffer overrun while writing to 'dynamicInts':  the writable size is 'someInts.public: unsigned int __thiscall std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> >::size(void)const ()*4' bytes, but '8' bytes might be written.
```

The *Detailed Explanation* in the *Error List* explains this as:

```
7: 'dynamicInts' is an array of 1 elements (4 bytes)
9: Enter this loop. (assume 'i<someInts.size()')
9: 'i' may equal 1
9: Continue this loop. (assume 'i<someInts.size()')
11: 'i' is an In/Out argument to 'std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> >::[]'
11: Invalid to write to 'dynamicInts[1]'. (writable range is 0 to 0)
```

These messages suggest that the analyser thinks the `dynamicsInts` array is only one element.

That seems odd. I know *"Code Analysis Is Hard",* but surely the analyser has all the information it needs right there to derive the array length and loop bound?

So is this just a false negative from the code analysis? Or am I missing something?

If it is a false negative then what's the best way to avoid this warning without adding suppression and assuming that we *need* to stick with dynamically-allocated arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly I can make the warning go away by introducing a pointless intermediate variable for the size of the array, like this:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> someInts{ 1, 2, 3 };
    size_t numberOfInts = someInts.size();

    int* dynamicInts = new int[numberOfInts];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfInts; i++)
    {
        dynamicInts[i] = someInts[i];
    }

    delete[] dynamicInts;
}
```

I have no idea why the Code Analyser likes this, but doesn't like the original code.

The Analyser is also happy if I use a smart pointer to hold the dynamic allocation, which is a bit neater and probably the way it should have been written in the first place.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> someInts{ 1, 2, 3 };

    std::unique_ptr<int[]> dynamicInts(new int[someInts.size()]);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < someInts.size(); i++)
    {
        dynamicInts[i] = someInts[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: I've no personal experience but a few posts like yours have made me wonder about the reliability of VS code analysis.